# Is there a Method to edit certain subkeys of a subkey in the Registry without declaring them all?

Tags: c#, registry

So far I only had to deal with single edits, but now I have to edit a few subkeys which are all bundled in another subkey.

Is there a way to edit the values of subkeys of a registry key I declared (e.g. I declare RegistryKey key = .... (@"SOFTWARE\beep), and in the beep subkey I would find meep1,meep2,meep3 etc, which I want to edit in the end), or do I have to declare every SubKey I want to edit values in on its own?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that one way of doing that would be by simply using the same method of declaring them, but instead giving them different values? 
Since if you declare a subkey that is not there yet, it's going to create it and put in the value you gave the method as parameter. But if it is already there, it's going to change the value to the new value you give it with the method.
So basically, the same way you created the subkeys in the first place. 
But don't beat me if I'm wrong, just a wild guess, never worked with registry edits before in C#.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this would work, but the problem is that even if I could create/edit the subkeys of this subkey, I wouldn't know how to edit the values of the created/edited subkeys of the subkey.

Answer (score 0):

You have to access all the subkeys.You can get the name of all subkeys using GetSubKeyNames() and then use OpenSubKey("name of sub key", true) to edit them individually. You need to get write access on the subkeys. Please also see:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registrykey(v=vs.110).aspx